# Upstart script which restarts service when file is created

Tags: upstart

I have created my own upstart script in /etc/init, which I can start and stop.

Now I want that service to be restarted when a file (/etc/my-app/restart-requested.txt) exists (or better is touched).

My solution with previous /etc/init.d/ service was a cron-job which regularily checked for the restart-file and called restart when the file existed.

Is there a better solution with upstart?

Comment: Use inotify - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait , wait for a file and do your action. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24955/29187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [incron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/)
2. Put `/etc/my-app/restart-requested.txt IN_CLOSE_WRITE restart myservice` into `/etc/incron.d/myservice`

Answer (score 1):

6 years later I've found out that upstarts guarantees that it first processes `stop on` and then `start on`:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ordering-of-stop-start-operations

This means that you can use

```
start on file FILE=/etc/my-app/restart-requested.txt EVENT=modify
stop on file FILE=/etc/my-app/restart-requested.txt EVENT=modify
```

Probably you don't need it anymore but I've faced same issue and found your question so maybe someone can use this solution in the future as well.